# IE and WordPress

Tags: css

I'm developing a WordPress based website. Using latest version of WordPress and Genesis theme. I've to use a seperate stylesheet for IE, how can I add that?
Sorry for this silly question, I'm new in web development :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, add these lines to functions.php of your theme.

```
add_action('wp_head','ie_only');
function ie_only(){ ?>

<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->

<?php }
```

Now create a css file with this name (ie-only.css) and put that into your theme's directory.